# Send/Post Message to other Application

Tags: c#, messaging, autohotkey

I would like to know if it is possible to `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` to/in other application even if it is not activated, or somehow to interact with that application without disturbing the user....

So far all I want to do is ***detect Pixels*** at specific coordinates than to ***Click*** on specific coordinates.

***Note:*** *Please do not misunderstood, the reason I want to detect Pixels and than Click, is because the button does not has Class ID.*

Comment: Sounds like an aimbot! It is possible.  Is the game/program you are doing this to use DirectX or OpenGL to render?

Comment: Please do not misunderstood, the reason I want to detect Pixels and than Click, is because the button does not has Class ID.
Its a program

Comment: You want to interact with an application without the user knowing?

Comment: there is difference between 'disturbing' and 'knowing', I used the word 'disturbing' and I meant it.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` to send mouse clicks at specific coordinates to a window.  The messages to send would be like `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, and `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`.  These messages can be sent with the window minimized or hidden.

If you have Visual Studio, there is an included application called Spy++ (and Spy++ 64 Bit).  If you use those programs and have them monitor the window messages to your target application, you can see the exact window messages that are sent when you manually click on the button.

It is difficult if not impossible to detect pixels when the window is not visible either due to being minimized, hidden, or just covered by another window.  If the application will be running in Vista or later, you might try creating a [DWM Live Thumbnail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the application inside your app and scanning the pixels from there to determine the button's location.

Hopefully this information will get you started or at least let you know how complicated this may be so you can make an informed decision to continue or not.

Comment: Determining the button location is kinda easy, but I want to know if it is showed, thats why i need the pixels, anyway, messages you mentioned can produce that clicks while window is minimized/hidden?